# Accessing ADLS from Python

Tags: python, json, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a simple python script which i wrote years ago which iterates through a local folder and converts the json files to csv.

I now need to convert this to run against a folder in an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 Account. The code is going to be executed in Azure Synapse Analytics using PySpark.
As the ADLS account and the Synapse account are linked, is it just a case of changing the Folder to point to the ADLS account or is there some sort of authentication that i need to add in?

```
import glob
import os
file_names = []
Folder = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\jsonfiles\\'

for filepath in glob.iglob(Folder+'/*.json'):

from pandas import json_normalize
import json

with open(filepath) as data_file:    
    d= json.load(data_file)  

df = json_normalize(d, 'results')
print (df)

csvname = (os.path.splitext( (os.path.basename(filepath)))[0]+'.parquet')
print(csvname)

df.to_csv(Folder+csvname)
print(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the workaround

**WAY - 1**

You can directly access your files by giving the url of the path. Here is the screenshot where I'm trying to read a json file from my adls storage.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_json("https://<YOUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net/<YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME>/<YOUR_FILE_NAME>")

print(df)
```

**WAY - 2**

You can load data from Azure Data Lake Store Gen 2 using -

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
account_name = "Your account name"
container_name = "Your container name"
relative_path = "Your path"
adls_path = 'abfss://%s@%s.dfs.core.windows.net/%s' % (container_name, account_name, relative_path)

df1 = spark.read.option('header', 'true') \
                .option('delimiter', ',') \
                .csv(adls_path + '/Testfile.csv')
```

For more information, you can refer [How to use Synapse notebooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks#bring-data-to-a-notebook)